# My FloatingActionButton show under my textviews and images

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

My FloatingActionButton show under my textviews and images(hide behind). i mean i can see it but instead of being over and float(the floating is ok) it is show behind..
this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:hilitapplication="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    hilitapplication:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />
  <ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="FredokaOne-Regular.ttf"
        android:textColor="#992747"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text3"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text4"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="FredokaOne-Regular.ttf"
        android:textColor="#992747"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text5"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_register"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_login"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_fs"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_addgh"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_worker"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_fsmenu"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_fr01"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_fr02"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_fr03"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />


    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"

        />
    <hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_q1"
        android:background="@null"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_q2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />


   </LinearLayout>



 </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

i can not understand why ... and off-course it is not clickable(even when its show between the texts or images..while scrolling..)

Comment: Paste your full xml code please.

Comment: move your FAB below ScrollView

Comment: it is not working as Scrollview can host only one direct child

Comment: @hilit Out it outside "ScrollvView" .Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your xml as follows:-

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:hilitapplication="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
 <ScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
  <LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="FredokaOne-Regular.ttf"
    android:textColor="#992747"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text3"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text4"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="FredokaOne-Regular.ttf"
    android:textColor="#992747"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text5"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_register"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_login"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_fs"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_addgh"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_worker"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_fsmenu"
    android:background="@null"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_fr01"
    android:background="@null"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_fr02"
    android:background="@null"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_fr03"
    android:background="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    />

<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />


<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"

    />
<hilitsh.com.user.hilitapplication.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    hilitapplication:fontName="raleway_medium.ttf"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_q1"
    android:background="@null"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_q2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />


   </LinearLayout>



  </ScrollView>
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/myFAB"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    hilitapplication:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />
     </RelativeLayout>
```